# Java read score from file

Tags: java, text-files

If I have a text file with the following appearance:
john1337 score: 80
may10 score: 23
dfawfawf score: 40
heyhey score: 100
flow32 score: 25

How do I read only the top 3 scores in order and display them?
So it would be:
heyhey score: 100
john1337 score: 80
dfawfawf score: 40

Im trying to avoid sorting the integers by the names i.e 'john1337'
and instead displaying the actual score-line in order, how do I do this?

Comment: Any attempt so far?

Comment: Read lines, parse them, create objects, put them into an array or list and then sort the list.

Comment: What do you mean by avoid sorting the integers? If you don't look at the score how can you get the top 3 scores?

Comment: I meant avoid sorting by the integers in the name, so you dont sort the 1337 in the name john1337.

Comment: Still thinking about how im going about it

Answer (score 1):

There is a stream solution just for educational purposes, but you probably should try to implement it classical way.

```
Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(o -> Integer.valueOf(o.split(":")[1].trim()));
Comparator<String> reversed = comparator.reversed();

Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH_TO_FILE))
        .sorted(reversed)
        .limit(3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here the `Comparator` is used to sort all lines by score. Then using `limit` the stream is truncated to be no longer than 3.

Comment: Sorry if I dont understand you correctly, but the code im trying with currently is:

Comment: Liked the solution +1

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the 3 top scores without knowing, where they are located in the file. So you need to know where the top scores are located in the file. For this, you need to read all scores from the file, parse the strings (eg. split at ":", remove the word " score" and trim the resulting strings), and evaluate the scores. You can sort them using a hashmap or similar. So, your idea is not possible using a simple text file as datasource. If you would use a database for example you could create a query, which returns the top 3 scores.